# Intermixed sequence of Push and pop operations why is this sequence not possible

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I'm studying for a final and I can't figure this question out:

> Suppose that a client performs an intermixed sequence of stack push and pop operations. The push operations push the integers 0 through 9 in order on to the stack; the pop operations print out the return value. Which of the following sequences could not occur?
>
> (a) 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5
>
> (b) 2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 9 0
> (c) 0 4 6 5 3 8 1 7 2 9
> (d) 4 6 8 7 5 3 2 9 1 0
> (e) All of these sequences are possible

The answer is C but im not sure how to come to that conclusion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, So the program always pushes 0-9 in that order, so looking at each line, we work out which order the pushes and pops happen

```
**The first line.**   - Stack is
Pushes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4  - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Pops   4, 3, 2, 1, 0  - []
Pushes 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  - [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Pops   9, 8, 7, 6, 5  - []

**Second line**  - Stack is  
Pushes 0, 1, 2   - [0, 1, 2]  
Pops   2, 1      - [0]  
Pushes 3, 4      - [0, 3, 4]  
Pops   4, 3      - [0]  
Pushes 5, 6      - [0, 5, 6]  
Pops   6, 5      - [0]  
Pushes 7, 8      - [0, 7, 8]  
Pops   8, 7      - [0]  
Pushes 9         - [0, 9]  
Pops   9, 0      - []  

**Third line**    - Stack is   
Pushes 0          - [0]  
Pops   0          - []  
Pushes 1, 2, 3, 4 - [1, 2, 3, 4]  
Pops   4,         - [1, 2, 3]  
Pushes 5, 6       - [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]  
Pops   6, 5, 3    - [1, 2]  
Pushes 7, 8       - [1, 2, 7, 8]  
Pops   8          - [1, 2, 7]   
Pops   ?
```

The next pop **MUST** be 7, because it was pushed before 8, it *cannot* be 1.

Answer (score 4):

This is not difficult to solve. You just start writing the sequence until you find the first popped number; then cross it out and continue. Now we can see why the third sequence cannot occur:

```
0 // Pop 0
-
1 2 3 4 // Pop 4
1 2 3
1 2 3 5 6 // Pop 6
1 2 3 5 // Pop 5
1 2 3 // Pop 3
1 2
1 2 7 8 // Pop 8
1 2 7 // And here it fails; you cannot possibly pop a 1 from the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

For any decreasing sub-sequence in the output sequence, you can not have `[a1, ..., an]` such that, there exist k, where `ak > a1` and `ak < an` and `ak` has not come before in the output and `ak` is not part of the sub-sequence `[a1, ..., an]`.

Here [8, 1] is one such sub-sequence, where 7 has not come before and still not part of the sub-sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 printed before 1 so when 1 was popped the numbers until 8 have been already pushed. But if that is the case, 2 has also been pushed and so it should be popped before 1.

EDIT: to be more verbose - if you have a value x and then a value y in the sequence and you have x > y and x is before y in the sequence, no value in the interval [y, x] may be met in the sequence after y.